# Flutter Problem about Constructor return type

Tags: flutter, dart

The constructor returns type 'dynamic' that isn't of expected type 'Widget'.dart(invalid_cast_new_expr)

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the guidelines on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask